# Google Custom Search API- Get results specific user location

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

As in normal Google search page, Google returns me results specific to my location. As i am considering/assuming for this, it gets my ip address my request, find uses location for it and returns the results.

I am writing the proxy server for search engines. So from user browser i get requests for some search terms and server returns search results.

I am curious to know, if from **Custom Search API** can i get the such results based on some  IP  address i provide or anything like that, so that i can mock the user location in my proxy server and pretend the Google Custom Search to be that user and get the location specific results

PS.I am new to this search engine api world, so please understand me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but just for the country, not the exact location.

Here is the docs for parameters of a query request:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list
Look at the 'gl' parameter.

I'm not aware of any way to specify the location more precisely then this.

Comment: One thing i want to ask, is api, by default returns the results based on useragent ip address?

Comment: can i make it to return it, so ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Your only option is the 'gl' parameter.

Comment: ```build("customsearch","v1",developerKey=api_key).cse()``` what to put here?

Comment: With the CR parameter you are filtering the results in order to show only pages from a certain country. So you're not setting the user's location as they search; you are filtering the results. They are two different things. At the moment I am also looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After these many years I'm not sure if you still need it, but I found it hard to find a helpful answear, so here's the solution for whoever needs it.

You can achieve that behavior with the "**?gl**=" query param as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list), and pass the value as one of the [country codes](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/json_api_reference#countryCodes).

Worked for me, hope it helps someone!